# List categories, subcategories and posts from custom taxonomy and custom post type

Tags: custom-post-types, wp-query, categories

I have custom taxonomy "oferta" and custom post type "produkt".

An "oferta" is needed to create categories and subcategories for posts in "produkt".

I have a lot of categories and subcategories
and I need to show pages according to the scheme:

- First I see main categories only
- When I choose one I see subcategories which belongs only to that category I choosed.
- Next I can choose another subcategory and so on.
- And on the last page I see list of posts which belongs to that particular subcategory only.

In addition, I need to hide subcategories that do not have posts.

In taxonomy-oferta.php I have code:

```
<section id="primary" class="site-content">
    <div id="content" role="main">

        <header class="entry-header">
            <h1 class="entry-title"><?php single_cat_title(); ?></h1>
        </header>

        <?php
        $term = get_queried_object();
        $term_id = $term->term_id;
        $taxonomy_name = $term->taxonomy;

        $termchildren = get_term_children( $term_id, $taxonomy_name );

        echo '<ul>';
        foreach ( $termchildren as $child ) {
            $term = get_term_by( 'id', $child, $taxonomy_name );
            echo '<li><a href="' . get_term_link( $term, $taxonomy_name ) . '">' . $term->name . '</a></li>';
        }
        echo '</ul>'; ?>




    <?php if ( have_posts() ) : ?>

        <?php
        while ( have_posts() ) : the_post();

            get_template_part( 'content', 'oferta' );

        endwhile;

            twentytwelve_content_nav( 'nav-below' );
        ?>

    <?php else : ?>
        <?php get_template_part( 'content', 'none' ); ?>
    <?php endif; ?>

    </div>
</section>
```

Effect is that I see everyting at once:

- Main categories
- Subcategories
- And below are all posts

When I click on subcategory I see all the sub-subcategories of that one and below all the posts from sub- and sub-subcategories.

Can anyone help me with this code to get the effect I described at the beginning?

Answer (score 1):

You just need to tweak the logic so that `if ( have_posts() ) :` is only run if `get_term_children()` is empty, which it will be on the lowest level:

```
$term = get_queried_object();
$term_id = $term->term_id;
$taxonomy_name = $term->taxonomy;

$termchildren = get_term_children( $term_id, $taxonomy_name );

if ( ! empty( $termchildren ) ) {
    echo '<ul>';

    foreach ( $termchildren as $child ) {
        $term = get_term_by( 'id', $child, $taxonomy_name );
        echo '<li><a href="' . get_term_link( $term, $taxonomy_name ) . '">' . $term->name . '</a></li>';
    }

    echo '</ul>';
} elseif ( have_posts() ) {
    while ( have_posts() ) : the_post();
        get_template_part( 'content', 'oferta' );
    endwhile;

    twentytwelve_content_nav( 'nav-below' );
} else {
    get_template_part( 'content', 'none' ); 
}
```

In that example I added `if ( ! empty( $termchildren ) )` and changed `if ( have_posts() )` to `elseif ( have_posts() )`.

Comment: Thanks Jacob! Almost there :-)
Now posts are displayed where they should be - in the last subcategories.
But I have one more puzzle here.
When I display the first page, which is the list of main categories - I can see sub-categories there as well.
Subcategories should be visible only after selecting one of the main categories. Could you please advise?